# Need to modify Shopify products API BY Shopify team then return back to me

Tags: shopify

It is necessary to modify Shopify products API as per my client requirement.

For example the below products API is available in Shopify API reference document.

GET /admin/products.json

I am able to get list of products from above API.  But i want to filter products based on price by sending price as input parameter and get related products as a response.

For that post API is needed.  Do shopify team provide Products API for filtering products by sending input parameter as that is not available in API reference?
Kindly give me the information.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to filter on a price range using `/admin/products.json`. You can page through all of the products, 250 at a time, and find the products that meet your criteria that way.

Comment: ok, thanks for your response.  Does Shopify provide API based on our requirement which is not available in the documents ?.  I verified all the API's those are in the documents but they are not fulfill my requirement.  I want to take a API from Shopify.  So kindly tell me how to get API from Shopify to filful my requirement.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Shopify is not free beers for anyone .... Unles your requirement is top demanding, you'll need to find a workaround.